# Diretório de salvamento de arquivo de configuração com escopo User C#

Tags: c#, app.config

Com relação aos arquivos de configuração no *C#*, sempre utilizei o `App.config` apenas para gravar *strings* de conexão e algumas variáveis somente leitura, mas atualmente precisei modificar alguns dados em tempo de execução, daí que veio a questão do **escopo**: `User` e `Application`.

**Escopo de Aplicação**

Somente-leitura e podem ser alteradas apenas em tempo de *design* ou através de modificação no arquivo `[AssemblyName].exe.config` entre sessões do aplicativo.

**Escopo de Usuário**

leitura e/ou gravação em tempo de execução e seus valores podem ser alterados e salvos no código.

A dúvida é a seguinte, ao executar o `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` para um arquivo de configuração com o escopo `User` **é possível alterar o local onde o arquivo com os dados persistidos será  salvo?**

No *Debug* da aplicação está salvando em

```
C:\Users\A_tuxpilgrim\AppData\Local\Nome_do_Projeto\Nome_do_Projeto.vshost._...\1.0.0\user.config
```

**obs:** Esse [artigo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) e essa pergunta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046907/app-config-user-vs-application-scope) ajudaram bastante, só faltou a questão do diretório mesmo.

Comment: Se não estou em erro os `Settings` do `user` são sempre armazenados nesse ficheiro, não há forma de alterar o local porque a ideia é mesmo essa: gravar a informação numa localização do utilizador. Mas porque não cria um ficheiro de config próprio? Aí consegue muito mais flexibilidade, pode encriptar a informação, definir a estrutura, etc.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @JoãoMartins! Como não vi uma forma de alterar essa questão do diretório vou usar um  `xml` "comum". Acho que para o meu caso é melhor ter mais flexibilidade mesmo, só estava vendo a possibilidade de usar os `Settings` pra isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível. [Este artigo fala um pouco sobre isso](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rprabhu/2005/06/29/client-settings-faq/).

Se você precisa do arquivo de configurações num local separado, deve escrever o seu próprio mecanismo para gerenciá-lo.

Comment: Tava procurando um artigo bacana assim mesmo @LINQ (sobre o porque de ser esse diretório em especial). Acabei por fazer um arquivo personalizado pra gerenciar as configurações que preciso.

Comment: Nice, eu também normalmente opto por fazer meu próprio, se tiver tempo. Btw, a resposta atende sua pergunta ou você precisa de mais detalhes? @Tuxpilgrim

Comment: Opa, foi esquecimento, marcada como resposta, o artigo atende sim o que queria :D